# static files don't visable in production | DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.11

I am little bit confused. I use [django-el-pagination](https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination) application in my project. This app use next javascript in template:

```
<script src="{% static 'el-pagination/js/el-pagination.js'%}"></script>
```

In works perfect in django development server, but in production it show 404.

In production I install this app. Here below my `settings.py` file:

```
DEBUG = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
```

Also I did `python manage.py collectstatic` command. What I forget to do?

Comment: What's your deployment methods ?

Comment: @misraX I update my post with more detailed settings. Can you check it now.

Comment: That still doesn't say how you are deploying it in production. Are you using ``python manage.py runserver`` in production, or are you using Apache/mod_wsgi, nginx/uWSGI, gunicorn or something else?

Comment: In production I use `nginx + gunicorn + supervisor` stack.

Comment: Then you probably need to show how you have configured nginx to serve the static files as gunicorn doesn't do it for you. The only way to have gunicorn do it for you is to use WhiteNoise middleware.

Comment: Share your nginx configuration, gunicorn script, supervisor, it will help to demonstrate the problem, where do you save your nginx log, the log also will help.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) :

> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will
>   be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).

Therefore if you don't use `runserver` and if `DEBUG` is set to `False` it should not serve those files.

Anyway, if you also consider this from the same documentation :

> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.

Here are [some suggested ways](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server) to serve staticfiles in production, the linked one for instance is about serving it with your reverse proxy server (nginx or apache for instance).

Comment: To tack onto this answer, if you don't want to deal with nginx or apache, whitenoise is a nice simple way to get your static files served. http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Comment: I update my post with more detailed settings. Also I use nginx gunicorn supervisor stack. If I just change to `DEBUG = False` in production, it will be enough?! What I must take into account more?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek You have to configure nginx to serve these files. I added a link.

Answer (score -1):

This is commonly happen with production server. You can access static files from your production server

```
<script src="https://techoryze.herokuapp.com/static/js/jquery.js" />
```

[image: Check the screenshot]

Comment: It's not ideal, or best practice to hardcode the static url, what if you changed the domain, what if you want to reuse your app in another project,,, what if... etc, All the hardcoded statics will be useless.